C++ Macro to add `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to formatted wxLog function calls
I have an application using wxWidgets, and I'm using the built-in wxLogging to print messages with wxLogError(msg).
Essentially, I want to have a macro that takes all my wxLogError calls and adds the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ string before the message. Like the example below:
#define wxLogError(msg)  wxLogError("%s - %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, msg)
However, I don't think it likes that it's replacing something that matches the pattern with another string that matches the pattern.
There is also the bigger issue that comes in when I want to support wxLogError calls that use the formatting, for E.G.
wxLogError("Error: Attempt %d failed with message %s", idx, msg)
As this would need to be recognized and replaced with the below to get the desired output.
wxLogError("%s - Error: Attempt %d failed with message %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, idx, msg)
I feel like this might be possible with some REGEX magic, but am a little lost on how to achieve this.
Is this possible? Can macros be used this way?
When I tried using #define wxLogError(msg)  wxLogError("%s - %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, msg), with the only wxLogError call being wxLogError("Test");; it complained that wxLogError was not declared within scope.
However, without the define to add the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ string, then wxLogError is within scope. So I'm assuming it is an issue with the macro.

If you have c++20, there is std::source_location which supersede the MACRO.

Avoid MACRO if possible, but it seems you want __VA_ARGS__.

A combination of std::source_location with std::format and good old std::fputs on stderr will do. If C++23 is available, then <print> gives std::print and std::println. Avoid C variadic functions; they're just a compatibility feature for interoperability with C modules.

@Jarod42 Btw, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is not really a macro. It cannot be #undef'd, its existence cannot be checked with #ifdef.

The simplest solution is to leave the macros alone and just define your own log formatter that prepends wxLogRecordInfo::func to the messages created by its overridden Format().
This will use __FUNCTION__ (or __func__ in 3.3) and not __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, however.
